# Solenoid bolt retraction power

Tags: power, solenoid

i am looking at getting a solenoid bolt like this for a project but the problem is alot of solenoid bolts that i have ordered can be retracted by pushing the bolt in manually so for example with your finger

i need a solenoid bolt which can only be retracted when power is supplied

Are all solenoids built like this or are there specific solenoids which can only be retracted with power on/off?

[image]

Comment: Apply power in the opposite direction to push the solenoid out. If you want to make it actually impossible to push it in, though, you're going to need multiple solenoids set up like a lock.

Comment: use a screw driven linear actuator instead

Comment: as @jsotola says, but consider what happens when power is off. Is this a safety critical function? It's much easier to provide a mechanical fallback to a solenoid than a screw driven actuator.

Comment: @Neil_UK, as stated  `i need a solenoid bolt which can only be retracted when power is supplied`